# Can I reload multiple divs with jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, reload

I'm currently trying to reload some divs by a class:

```js
jQuery(".avatar-wrapper").load(location.href + " .avatar-wrapper>*", "");
```

```css
img {
  width: 80px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="avatar-wrapper">
  <img class="avatar" src="https://target.scene7.com/is/image/Target/GUEST_7f86ff7a-22f0-4556-997c-b6dc907a1940?wid=488&hei=488&fmt=pjpeg">
</div>

<div class="avatar-wrapper">
  <img class="avatar" src="https://target.scene7.com/is/image/Target/GUEST_7f86ff7a-22f0-4556-997c-b6dc907a1940?wid=488&hei=488&fmt=pjpeg">
</div>
```

I've multiple elements with the same class on a page so I expected that all elements getting reloaded with this but sadly it don't works. Maybe I need a direct reference but the best option would be one line of code. Any ideas how I can deal with this?

Comment: You url parameter of `load` seems to have wrong format. What is the supposed meaning of `" .avatar>"*`?

Comment: @BoltKey it's a selector to pick an element from the response. See [Loading Page Fragments](http://api.jquery.com/load/#loading-page-fragments).

Comment: The selector selects no elements, since `.avatar` elements have no (direct) children.

Comment: @BoltKey ah yeah, good point

Comment: Wouldn't your jquery selector return an array of elements for which to iterate through? It's been a couple months since I last used jquery, but maybe loop through it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

jQuery's `.load()` loads remote content **into** page elements. `<img>` elements are content-less so this is not going to work. You'd be better off removing all your images then replacing them with the ones from a `$.post()` response, eg

```js
$.post(location.href).done(doc => {
  $('.avatar').remove()
  $(doc).find('.avatar').appendTo('#some-container-element')
})
```

---

Alternately, reload an element that wraps your images

```js
$('#some-container-element').load(`${location.href} #some-container-element`, '')
```

Comment: What if I put a wrapper around it and reload the wrapper? Is this possible with one main class like jQuery(".wrapper").load(location.href + " .wrapper>*", "");?

Comment: Ok thats the better solution I think. I'll try it out. Thanks for the hint mate!

Comment: Seems to be not working. I've now two wrappers with the class avatar-wrapper but I've now 2 images in one wrapper lol

Comment: The problem with using classes is that there are multiple wrappers. You're telling jQuery to replace the contents of each of your wrappers with all the matched wrappers in the response, hence the duplicates. I strongly suggest using a single, ID'd wrapper

Comment: Finally did it with the help of your question. Thanks for helping me!